# Store user's email when he/she clicks on a certain button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to store the email of a user when he/she clicks on a (download) button, on a certain page. I can't find a solution for this problem. Hopefully you can help me out.

This is the code from the button itself:

```
<div class="my_music_download_2">
  <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x" href=" 
  <%= my_music.download %>" download></a>                    
</div>
```

I used devise for my authentication.

Comment: I would add a click event listener on the link with a function that posts the user email variable to an endpoint in your app

Comment: So I added this under my code:
<script> 
document.getElementById("try").addEventListener("click", function(){ 

}); 
</script>
 
 My javascript is really bad so I don't no how to write the function itself. Could you help me further please?

Comment: Sure you need to have something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/dadacruz/euczfxaq/26/ then checkout ajax or the fetch api or a library like axios to post the data

Comment: Could you maybe show me how i get the email of a user when he clicks the button and how I can display that user (and all the other user's who clicked that button ) on a different page in this case the /data page?

Comment: All you have to do put your erb something like <%= user.email %> in a hidden input in the javascript just get that element and post. Do you have a public repo ?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/Maartensdb/steven-de-baecke/tree/fixes , Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but you could just handle it in the controller.

You put something like this in your **view**:

```
<%= link_to "download", download_music_path, class: "fas fa-file-download fa-3x" %>
```

And then have this in your **controller**:

```
def download_music
  current_user.update(email: "new@email.com")
  redirect_to my_music.download
end
```

I assumed that you want to update the email of a person that is logged in. Also, it's up to you how you pass the email and where do you get the download link, but this is what I understand from your question.